# scope management in RxJs

Tags: rxjs

Here, I'm mixing both RxJS and promise-mysql..

```
const mysql = require('promise-mysql');
const Rx = require('rxjs/Rx');
```

I establish a connection with this:

var conn;
var queryString = `select product_id, set_complete_in from mi_product limit 2`;

`var conn;
  const obs = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'somehost',
  user: 'someuser',
  password: 'some password',
  database: 'someday'
 }));`

at this point the obs is a promise that may or not be resolve.

Here I set up a series of queries.. (basically a fan out, in of queries in parallel)

```
const responseStream = obs
                .flatMap(connection => {
                     conn = connection;

                    //submitArray is an array of IDs
                   var requestStream = submitArray.map(id => Rx.Observable.fromPromise(connection.query(queryString, [id])));
                 //run these in parallel
                   return Rx.Observable.forkJoin(requestStream);
                });
```

//it's an array of arrays so flatten..

```
responseStream.subscribe(resp => 
{ 
 returnValue = resp.reduce((accum,  arr) => {return accum.concat(arr);}, []);
 console.log('returnValue is ', JSON.stringify(returnValue));
//call back here to return the data
}
,
err => {console.log('!!!!!!err is ', err);},
() => {console.log('connection end!'); conn.end();});
```

this all works, but my question is how to handle the connection.  As you can see, I define the connection at a higher scope so it's available in the subscribe callback.  It doesn't seem very functional to call conn.end() in the subscription.. It seems like I should be handling it within the responseStream definition.  Does this seem correct?

Comment: That is some horribly formatted code. Please format your code at least in the question if you choose to not format it in your project.

Comment: sorry.. var conn; is declared outside of the responseStream.

Comment: how's that?  a little better?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a little bit hard to follow, but I think your problem is that you need access to your connection, from your promise, but you won't have access to it in a completion callback without mixing up scopes. If I were implementing this feature, I would solve this by ditching the `fromPromise` usage and creating my own stream. When subscribers were done with my stream, I'd clean up the connection.

```
Rx.Observable.create( observer => {
  const createConnection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'somehost',
    user: 'someuser',
    password: 'some password',
    database: 'someday'
  });

  /* forward the connection and any errors to observer */
  createConnection.then( observer.next, observer.error );

  return function cleanUp() {
    /* end the connection when we are done */
    createConnection.then( connection => connection.end() );
  };
});
```

This ensures that any "connection close" operation is handled by the source stream, a pattern that is common and advantageous when working with observables.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying..  thanks for responding to this.

Comment: actually, after doing a bit more reading, I can place a call to connection.end() anywhere after submission of the connection.query(..).  the connection will allow completion of any pending queries prior to ending the connection.